# build gimp separate-plus: undefined reference to symbol 'pow@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

Tags: 16.04, compiling, gcc, gimp, color-management

How can I get the Makefile of separate+0.5.8 to build the respective gimp plugin?

### Problem description

Following the usual

```
make
sudo make install
```

steps for separate+-0.5.8 with lcms2 (uncommented the entry line 3 in the Makefile of separate+) I encounter the error

> /usr/bin/ld: separate-core.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pow@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
>   //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

The gcc commands that the Makefile processed are (after that you see the error messages from above):

```
gcc -g -DUSE_LCMS2 `pkg-config gimp-2.0 --cflags` `pkg-config gimpui-2.0 --cflags` `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags` `pkg-config lcms2 --cflags` -DENABLE_COLOR_MANAGEMENT -DENABLE_NLS -DGETTEXT_PACKAGE="\"gimp20-separate\"" -DUSE_ICC_BUTTON -c lcms_wrapper.c
gcc -g  separate-core.o separate-gui.o separate-export.o util.o tiff.o psd.o jpeg.o iccbutton.o lcms_wrapper.o -o separate `pkg-config gimp-2.0 --libs` `pkg-config gimpui-2.0 --libs` `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs` `pkg-config lcms2 --libs` -ltiff -ljpeg
/usr/bin/ld: separate-core.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pow@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

### misc

Done on a elementaryOS 0.5 (ubuntu 16.04).
Some steps made before make:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gimp gimp-dds gimp-gap gimp-lensfun gimp-gmic gimp-plugin-registry gimp-data-extras gimp-dcraw icc-profiles icc-profiles-free pandora 
wget http://sourceforge.jp/projects/separate-plus/downloads/47873/separate+-0.5.8.zip
sudo apt install libgimp2.0-dev libtiff5-dev
sudo apt install liblcms2-2 liblcms2-dev liblcms2-utils
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this issue.  I thought it was out of order libraries but it looks like I just needed to include the math library.  Edit the Makefile like so:

- among the library listings (pkgconfig stuff) add a line for math lib like:

  ```
  M_LIB = -lm
  ```
- comment old library listing and add new one like:

  ```
  LIBS = $(M_LIB) $(GIMP_LIB) $(GTK_LIB) $(LCMS_LIB) $(TIFF_LIB) $(JPEG_LIB)
  ```

The linker should now stop complaining.  Be sure and set your PREFIX to something local if installing to your home dir, as po/Makefile will try to install locale files under /usr otherwise.

Hope that helps.